# collect2.exe Error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++

При компиляции проекта в файле main.cpp возникает ошибка:

> Error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> в пути C:\директория\proj\collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Причём папка `proj` создалась сама в папке с `*cpp` и `*.h` во время компиляции.   А файла `collect2.exp` там нету.

Comment: Проверьте все сообщения компилятора. Возможно при компиляции или работе редактора связей возникла ошибка, которая не позволила создать загрузочный модуль.

Comment: @Vlad  
...\main.o In function `ZStorSt13_Ios_OpenmodeS_':  
...\main.cpp multiple definition of `main'  
...\proj\collect2.exe [Error] ld returned 1 exit status  
Такие вот ошибки

Comment: У вас должно быть одно определение функции main, и вы не можете вызывать ее рекурсивно. Поэтому проверьте, вызывает ли main саму себя.

Comment: @Vlad  
Может ли ошибка multiple definition of `main' -- *.cpp:6: first defined here
Говорить о том, что ошибка вызвана тем, что функция int main(int argv, char *argc[]){ использована дважды в друх разных файлах

Comment: Да, возможно, что вы определили main в двух различных единицах компиляции, которые собираются в один загрузочный модуль.

Comment: Не "может ли", а так и есть. И дело не только в `main()`, не может существовать более одной функции с одним и тем же именем (и одинаковыми сигнатурами, но к `main()` это не относится, она всегда должна быть одна)

Comment: @Pink Что же мне тогда делать? Эта функция нужна и там и там, но компилятор не принимает такой вариант :/

Comment: Не нужна вам `main()` 2 раза. Никому она больше одного раза не нужна. Это - единственная точка входа в программу, и второй быть не может.

Comment: @Pink проблема решена, благодарю